# Powershell AD tool

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

Basically, I've created a 400+ and growing AD tool with a GUI. I've given them the option to search using many filters with get-aduser and wild cards fill the rest. This company is large so when I search for a common name like kyle or john, it takes along time to pull the information because the search was not specific.
Is there a way to stop them from doing such a general search or limit the number of entries can be in an array, or stop the search if there's too much information.

Edit: I have a solution using a variable to count wild cards but that only works if the form is completely blank. If i set the number any different they won't be able to look someone up by ID number

Comment: This may be helpful. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b5b439fe-1aa9-4823-a3ac-d0be643a5073/query-using-ad-module-timed-out?forum=winserverDS The top answer suggest using `Get-ADObject`.

Comment: Great idea, however I'm using -properties *. If I can maybe define that some way. Just fyi there's over 300k accounts being searched.

Comment: Can you show us some examples of how your filtering is being performed in the code? Using different LDAP filters might produce different rates of performance.

Comment: You can use the -ResultSetSize parameter on Get-ADUser to limit the number of results returned.

Comment: Get-aduser -f {IDnumber -like $Var1 -and name -like $var2...etc 9 more filters} -properties *

Comment: I've never used param {} before how would that even look with get-aduser

Comment: if you're just looking for a tool, this one is pretty nice, however, i don't know if you can modify AD, only query it: https://sourceforge.net/projects/adhelper/

Comment: Resultsetsize worked, I didn't see it but looked again and found it. Sorry for the hassle and thanks!